# NEC Corporation uPD720200 USB 3.0 controller doesn't run at full speed

Tags: 10.10, usb, 32-bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [USB 3.0 card not recognized](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26471/usb-3-0-card-not-recognized)

I have fresh install of Ubuntu 10.10. I have external HD on USB 3.0. Trying to connect this via PCI Express NEC controller.

dmesg:

```
[ 8966.820078] usb 6-3: new high speed USB device using xhci_hcd and address 0 
[ 8966.839831] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: WARN: short transfer on control ep 
[ 8966.840580] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: WARN: short transfer on control ep 
[ 8966.841329] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: WARN: short transfer on control ep 
[ 8966.842079] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: WARN: short transfer on control ep 
[ 8966.843343] scsi8 : usb-storage 6-3:1.0 
[ 8967.847144] scsi 8:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SAMSUNG  HD204UI          1AQ1 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5 
[ 8967.847589] sd 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0 
[ 8967.847923] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] 3907029168 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 TB/1.81 TiB) 
[ 8967.848341] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: WARN: Stalled endpoint 
[ 8967.850959] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off 
[ 8967.850963] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00 
[ 8967.850966] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through 
[ 8967.851818] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: WARN: Stalled endpoint 
[ 8967.852365] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through 
[ 8967.852370]  sdb: sdb1 
[ 8967.871315] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: WARN: Stalled endpoint 
[ 8967.871853] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through 
[ 8967.871856] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk 
[ 8967.950728] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: WARN: Stalled endpoint 
[ 8967.951355] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense Key : Recovered Error [current] [descriptor] 
[ 8967.951361] Descriptor sense data with sense descriptors (in hex): 
[ 8967.951363]         72 01 04 1d 00 00 00 0e 09 0c 00 00 00 00 00 00 
[ 8967.951375]         00 00 00 00 00 50 
[ 8967.951380] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] ASC=0x4 ASCQ=0x1d 
[ 8968.790076] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: HC died; cleaning up 
[ 8968.790076] usb 6-3: USB disconnect, address 2 
[ 8999.008554] scsi 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Unhandled error code 
[ 8999.008558] scsi 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Result: hostbyte=DID_TIME_OUT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK 
[ 8999.008562] scsi 8:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 74 70 97 39 00 00 3e 00 
[ 8999.008573] end_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 1953535801 
[ 8999.008578] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 1953535738 
[ 8999.008582] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 1953535739 
[ 8999.008585] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 1953535740 
[ 8999.008589] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 1953535741 
[ 8999.008592] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 1953535742 
[ 8999.008595] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 1953535743 
[ 8999.008600] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 1953535744 
[ 8999.008603] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 1953535745 
[ 8999.008606] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 1953535746 
[ 8999.008609] Buffer I/O error on device sdb1, logical block 1953535747 
[ 8999.008642] scsi 8:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device 
[ 8999.008747] scsi 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Unhandled error code 
[ 8999.008749] scsi 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK 
[ 8999.008752] scsi 8:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 74 70 97 77 00 00 3e 00 
[ 8999.008760] end_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 1953535863
```

sudo lspci -v

```
2:00.0 USB Controller: NEC Corporation uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 03) (prog-if 30)

    Physical Slot: 32

    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16

    Memory at fe9fe000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]

    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3

    Capabilities: [70] MSI: Enable- Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+

    Capabilities: [90] MSI-X: Enable- Count=8 Masked-

    Capabilities: [a0] Express Endpoint, MSI 00

    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting

    Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff

    Capabilities: [150] #18

    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

    Kernel modules: xhci-hcd
```

If I try to put into this controller any USB 2.0, it works fine. But USB 3.0 nope. Any idea?